# Show image for control on toolboxservice

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show an image next to the name of the control on a toolbox service. So i have tried to use ToolboxBitmapAttribute or a hardcode bitmap. However, it is still not shown up when the form is loaded. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
public void PopulateToolbox(ToolboxService lstToolbox)
        {
            ToolboxItem toolboxButton = new ToolboxItem(typeof(Button));
            ToolboxBitmapAttribute tba 
                =TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(toolboxButton)[typeof(ToolboxBitmapAttribute)] as ToolboxBitmapAttribute;
            if (tba != null)
                toolboxButton.Bitmap = (Bitmap)tba.GetImage(toolboxButton);
            toolboxButton.DisplayName = "Custom Button";
            // also does not work
            //toolboxButton.Bitmap = new Bitmap(0x10, 0x10);
            lstToolbox.AddToolboxItem(toolboxButton);
            lstToolbox.AddToolboxItem(new ToolboxItem(typeof(UITextBox)));                
        }
```

[image]

Comment: is the variable `tba` null?

Comment: No, it is not the case. The tba is not null. If i set "toolboxButton.Bitmap = new Bitmap(0x10, 0x10);", it also does not work.